# Averaging when events are slower than measurement time

Tags: math, average, rate, digital

I'm trying to come up with a better way of providing an instantaneous average when input signal is very slow. This seems like a math-y kinda question so if it should be over there let me know.

I have events that are measured as a pulse. Normally I can collect the pulses in a counter and then read the counter value at a fixed interval, say 1/4 second. I can then take the count value and divide by the number of seconds so n/0.25 and get a rate. I then apply a low pass filter to clean up the average and that works great normally.

What do I do when the events happen once every 1-60 seconds? The obvious choice is to wait until I have a sufficient number of counts and divide by total time. However, I need to provide the user with a reading every few seconds so waiting is not an option. I need some way to estimate the value.

I've thought of one solution that's kinda hard to explain. I was wondering if there was a standard way of doing this. I'm pretty sure I have to utilize a different kind of "data," the lack of an event. The goal is to estimate until enough time/events have passed to really calculate a rate and to transition from estimate to real rate seamlessly.

Comment: There's a lot of literature about sampling low frequency data. Review radioactivity, seismology, etc. Voting as off-topic since this isn't programming specific.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly are you measuring the pulses, and what does each pulse represent in your measurement?

Comment: @tehhowch Actually it is radiation based. Do you have any recommendations, I haven't had much luck?

Comment: @Guille Basically a rising edge is counted in a hardware counter in a micro-controller.

Comment: Maybe you can implement two measurement modes. The first one, as you are currently doing, is to measure pulse count in a time interval. The other mode, for low frequencies, could be implementing a time measurement between two pulses using a timer peripheral. As soon as a new pulse comes, you have a new value..